# Why is the sum of standard deviation of random effects in lme4 output greater than the actual sd of the variable itself?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

```
library(lme4)
data("sleepstudy")
m_avg <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + (1|Subject),sleepstudy)
summary(m_avg)
Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Subject  (Intercept) 1278     35.75   
Residual             1959     44.26   
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

sd(sleepstudy$Reaction)
[1] 56.32876
```

I expected that the between subject variability and the residual variability together forms the complete partition of the observed variability. I am surprised to see that the sum of bsv and residual variability is much higher than the observed variability. Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The total variablity is equal to the square root of the sum of the squares of the individual variabilities.

So this this case:

```
 56.32^2 = (35.75^2 + 44.26^2)
```

Due to rounding error in the individual variabilities there is a slight error.

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e As an extension to this question, if I would like to calculate the between subject variability (BSV) of X, can I apply delta method  to the BSV of sqrt(X) [All I have is the BSV of sqrt(X), I had to square root transform X so that it follows normal distribution]? Could you please show the derivation if possible?

Comment: @Ruser, welcome to CV! Since the answer posted here seems to address the issue in the original question, I advice you to post a new question for these follow-up questions. You can add a link to this question in the new one if you want to make the connection clear.